# A question on hypothetical syllogism

Tags: logic

hypothetical syllogism is of the form:

if a then b

if b then c

Therefore, if a then c .

In one of the examples my book also says

F ⊃ G

~ G ⊃ F

Therefore ~G ⊃ G (by HS)

I have a small problem of contradiction

It's like saying if not fire then fire (??)
Can someone give a material example
To this kind of conclusion?
Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129497/discussion-on-question-by-dasem-a-question-on-hypothetical-syllogism).

Answer (score 1):

A *précis* of formal logic...

> **~G** and **G** are contradictory to each other.

Yes, and thus formula "**~G and G**" is a contradiction, i.e. a formula that is always False. See [truth table for Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Truth_table).

> **~G ⊃ G** is not always false, and thus is not a contradiction.

When **G** is True, **~G** is False and "False ⊃ True" is True (see truth table for [Conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Definition_of_material_implication)).

> **~G** logically implies **G** ?

Obviously not, because when the premise **~G** is True, the conclusion **G** is False.

> **~G ⊃ G** logically implies **G** ?

Yes, because the only case when the premise is True is when **G** is True, and thus the condition defining [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) is satisfied.

---

What is the link between *conditional* and *logical consequence*?

We have that **A** implies **B** iff **A ⊃ B** is a tautology and the examples above are consistent with this fact:

> **~G ⊃ G** is not a tautology, and **~G** does not logically imply **G**.

> **(~G ⊃ G) ⊃ G** is a tautology, and **~G ⊃ G** logically implies **G**.

---

---

Regarding now the "puzzling" example of HS above:

> F ⊃ G

> ~ G ⊃ F

> > Therefore ~G ⊃ G (by HS)

the fact that the conclusion is False when **G** is False does not contradict the validity of the HS rule.

A rule of inference is valid when the conclusion il a logical consequence of the premises.

What happens when **~G ⊃ G** is False?

We have seen that the conclusion is False just in case when **G** is False; but in this case the two premises cannot be both True.

The premises are both True only when **G** is True, and in this case also the conclusion is.